# react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] error after install react-native-vision-camera

Tags: android, react-native, cmake, react-native-reanimated, react-native-vision-camera

After the install of react-native-vision-camera there is this error that shows up. I've tried to downgrade the versions but again i can the same error.

Error:
react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
76 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 71 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.

And these are the versions i use:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "^0.70.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.14.1"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried something from this thread https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1283

Comment: Yep, everything i think. Nothing seems to work. I do not know if i downgrade react native version but i prefered not

Comment: from your settings - try to remove ^ because, in reality, it can install a higher version. like described here https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1283#issuecomment-1282304728

Comment: i deleted them and it show up something else.
react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\layoutReanimation\ReanimatedUIManager.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
class ReaUiImplementationProvider extends UIImplementationProvider {
                                          ^
  symbol: class UIImplementationProvider

Comment: yep it is another problem with react native try this https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3743#issuecomment-1304127794

Comment: unfortunately it shows me the previus mistake.
react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]
 [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using \node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed

Comment: you need to check your node_modules and gradlew which particular version you have

Comment: 99% problem with your local versions of libraries

Comment: buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31}
what should i check in the node_modules? Thanks for the help

Comment: node_modules\react-native-reanimated\package.json 
node_modules\react-native-vision-camera\package.json 
version property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249353/discussion-between-thnikas-and-kirill-novikov).

Answer (score 1):

I today faced this problem, here are the steps I followed to solve it:

1. Changed package versions

   - "react-native-reanimated": "2.10.0"
   - "react-native-vision-camera": "2.14.1"
2. Run in root folder `rm -rf node_modaules` and `yarn` or `npm install`
3. And added this lines in file `./android/build.gradle`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L4H0.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXyBz.png)
4. In `android` folder run: `./gradlew clean` and after that run any commands (`./gradlew bundleRelease`, `./gradlew assembleRelease`)

Answer (score 0):

```
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.12.0",
```

change your package.json

Comment: nope not working i've just tried it

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem, here are the steps I followed to solve it:

1. I updated react-native version from `0.70.5` to `0.70.6`
2. I made sure to update **react-native-reanimated** and **react-native-vision-camera** versions as follows:

```json
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.2",
```

3. To avoid the error mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326839/error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugnativelibs/74342523#74342523), I added the following code in `android/build.gradle` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74342523/11686855):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
   // ...
   exclusiveContent {
      filter {
          includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
      }
      forRepository {
          maven {
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

4. I cleared caches in `./android` folder with `gradlew clean` command
5. And finally I rebuild the app with `yarn run android` command

Answer (score 0):

Run the following based on your build, you might not need the pod install.

- watchman watch-del-all
- yarn cache clean --force
- npm cache clean --force # optional - in case you have used npm
- rm -rf node_modules/ rm yarn.lock
- rm package-lock.json # optional - in case you have used npm
- rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
- rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*
- yarn install / npm install
- yarn start --reset-cache
- cd ios && rm -rf Podfile.lock && rm -rf Pods/ && pod install --verbose